# Android - conditional button display based on Volley response

Tags: android, android-volley

I'm sending a request via Volley, it returns some json like this:

`{"voted_for":true}` or `{"voted_for":false}`

I want the type of button I display in the layout to offer the inverse. So if a user has voted for the object, they have a button to unvote. Likewise, if the haven't voted for it, they can have a button to vote for it. The button itself will function the same regardless - sending another request via Volley to flip the vote at the server api.

How can I condition which button is shown (ex: filled heart vs. empty heart) on the response I receive with volley?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am understanding your requirement and status correctly, I think the solution is that:

```
Object voted_for = ClassVolley.fromJson(volleyRet);
if(voted_for) {
    btn.setSrc("heart.png");
} else {
    btn.setSrc("empty_heart.png");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Robin's answer is correct and should work for you.

Another option would be

```
if(response.equals("voted_for") {
  btn.setText("Unvote");
else {
  btn.setText("Vote);
}
```